# Ternary operator in GraphQL filter

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client

Can I use ternary operator in a GraphQL filter? I want to filter using a variable but I get an error `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "=".`

```
query GetQuery($env: String) {
    category (filter: { page: { status: { 
        _in: $env == "production" ? [ "published" ] : [ "published", "draft"]
    }}}) {
        // query here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: no.

Such logic should be executed outside the graphql query and then provided as a variable.

```
const status = (env == "production") ? [ "published" ] : [ "published", "draft"]

const query = gql`
query GetQuery($status: String) {
    category (filter: { page: { status: { _in: $status }}}) {
        // query here
    }
}`
```